Search for text in workbook and hyperlink to matching Sheet name
I'm trying to search 94+ sheets and hyperlink text in columns to matching worksheets in the workbook.
Sub test()
    Dim mySht As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, myRng As Range

    Set mySht = ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In mySht.Range("B7:B200", ["H7:H200"])
        For Each sht In Worksheets
            If sht.Name <> mySht.Name Then    ' find each worksheet except myself
                Set myRng = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set myRng = sht.Cells.Find(what:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)    ' find match
                If Not myRng Is Nothing Then
                    mySht.Hyperlinks.Add _
                        anchor:=cell, _
                        Address:="", _
                        SubAddress:=myRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, True), _
                        TextToDisplay:=cell.Value
                    Exit For
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next sht
    Next cell
End Sub

I found two issues:

I have to run it one sheet at a time. I changed worksheet to ThisWorkbook and ran into a handful of errors. (Second Code section)

I'm missing something on range. It doesn't just run on Cells B7:B200 and H7:H200 it hyperlinks everything in C:G.


Sub test() 
Dim mySht As ThisWorkbook, sht As ThisWorkbook Dim cell As Range, myRng As Range
Set mySht = ThisWorkbook
For Each cell In mySht.Range("B7:B200", ["H7:H200"])
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook
        If sht.Name <> mySht.Name Then    ' find each worksheet except myself
            Set myRng = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set myRng = sht.Cells.Find(what:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)    ' find match
            If Not myRng Is Nothing Then
                mySht.Hyperlinks.Add _
                    anchor:=cell, _
                    Address:="", _
                    SubAddress:=myRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, True), _
                    TextToDisplay:=cell.Value
                Exit For
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next sht
Next cell
End Sub


Compile error: Method or Data member not found


Create Hyperlinks to Cells with Values Found in all Worksheets

For each value in the given range of the destination sheet (Sheet1), it will loop through all other (source) worksheets (tabs from left to right) and try to find the value. If the value is found, it will replace the value in the destination sheet with a hyperlink to the found cell and continue searching for the next value.


Sub GenerateHyperlinks()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containinig this code
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' !!!
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("B7:B200,H7:H200")
    drg.Hyperlinks.Delete ' clear existing hyperlinks
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, scell As Range, dcell As Range
    Dim dValue As Variant, IsValueValid As Boolean

    For Each dcell In drg.Cells
        dValue = dcell.Value
        IsValueValid = False
        If Not IsError(dValue) Then ' no error
            If Len(dValue) > 0 Then IsValueValid = True ' not blank
        End If
        If IsValueValid Then
            For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
                If sws.Name <> dws.Name Then
                    Set scell = sws.UsedRange.Find(What:=dValue, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    If Not scell Is Nothing Then
                        dws.Hyperlinks.Add _
                            Anchor:=dcell, _
                            Address:="", _
                            SubAddress:="'" & sws.Name & "'!" & scell.Address, _
                            TextToDisplay:=CStr(dValue)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next sws
        End If
    Next dcell

    MsgBox "Hyperlinks generated.", vbInformation

End Sub


This is closer to what I'm looking for, now if I change
Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' !!!  to Dim dws As Workbook: Set dws = Thisworkbook ' !!! 
Would this allow me to have all text in Cells B7:B200 & H7:H200 that match worksheets within the workbook hyperlink?

No, this would break the code. I don't understand what "all text in Cells B7:B200 & H7:H200 that match worksheets within the workbook hyperlink" means. Could you split this in a few sentences?

When I pull a report, in generates a work book with named sheets. Those names end up in columns B7:B200 and H7:H200 of each sheet, What I’m trying to accomplish with the macro is to go through all the sheets in the workbook and hyperlink the names in those cells to the corresponding sheet that is named in those cells

IE: Sheet 1 is “PN001” and cell B7 references “PN008” and H7 references “PN016”
What I’m trying to accomplish with the macro is to run through the entire workbook and hyperlink those cells to the sheets as the workbooks can be 94-900 sheets
The sheets aren’t always named the same when the report poles.

Here's another example on how to segment your code for readability.
Option Explicit

Function SearchForSheetName(ByVal shtName As String) As Worksheet
    '--- set the return in case we don't find it
    Set SearchForSheetName = Nothing
    If shtName = "" Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.name = shtName Then
            Set SearchForSheetName = sh
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sh
End Function

Sub MainProcess()
    Dim wsWithNames As Worksheet
    Set wsWithNames = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    With wsWithNames
        Dim nameRange As Range
        Set nameRange = Union(.Range("B7:B200"), .Range("H7:H200"))
        
        Dim nameCell As Range
        For Each nameCell In nameRange
            Debug.Print "nameCell at " & nameCell.Address
            If nameCell.Value <> "" Then
                Dim foundWS As Worksheet
                Set foundWS = SearchForSheetName(nameCell.Value)
                If Not foundWS Is Nothing Then
                    nameCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=nameCell, _
                                            Address:="", _
                                            SubAddress:="'" & nameCell.Value & "'!A1", _
                                            TextToDisplay:=nameCell.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next nameCell
    End With
End Sub



ThisWorkbook is the object that holds the VBA code; it is not a variable type, so it cannot be used with Dim.
I assume B7:B200,H7:H200 is on the ActiveSheet, please adjust if it's on a different sheet.
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets is the worksheet collection.

Sub test()
    Dim mySht As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, myRng As Range
    ' Assume the keyword list is on ActiveSheet
    Set mySht = ActiveSheet
    ' If not, change to
    ' Set mySht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TargetSheetName")
    For Each cell In mySht.Range("B7:B200,H7:H200")
        ' skip blank cells
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
            ' loop through all worksheets
            For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If sht.Name <> mySht.Name Then    ' find each worksheet except myself
                    Set myRng = Nothing
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set myRng = sht.Cells.Find(what:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)    ' find match
                    On Error GoTo 0 ' enabled error handler
                    If Not myRng Is Nothing Then
                        mySht.Hyperlinks.Add _
                            anchor:=cell, _
                            Address:="", _
                            SubAddress:=myRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, True), _
                            TextToDisplay:=cell.Value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next sht
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub


